# How to replace the deprecated "--" prefix decrement operator in comparisons?

Tags: swift, xcode, int, swift3, boolean

Before I used `--theX > 0` and it worked fine.

Excerpt of old code:

```
if --theX < 0 {
    ...
if ++theX < 0 {
    ...
if ++theX > worldSize.width + 1  {
    ...
if --theX > worldSize.height  {
    ...
```

Below you can see four lines of code that have `theX - 1 > 0` or something similar. Now that I've updated to Swift 3 I thought it would be easy to just change `--theX` to either `theX - 1` or `theX -= 1`.

Attempt of updated code:

```
func move(_ point:Point, worldSize:WorldSize) -> (Point) {
    var theX = point.x 
    var theY = point.y
    switch self {
    case .left:
        if theX - 1 < 0 {
            // theX = worldSize.width - 1
            print("g.o.")
            stopped = true
        }
    case .up:
        if theY + 1 < 0 {
            // theY = worldSize.height - 1
            print("g.o.")
            stopped = true
        }
    case .right:
        if theX + 1 > worldSize.width + 1  {
            // theX = 0
            print("g.o.")
            stopped = true
        }
    case .down:
        if theY - 1 > worldSize.height {
            //  theY = 0
            print("g.o.")
            stopped = true
        }
    }
    return Point(x: theX, y: theY)
  }
}
```

However, it seems that is not working ("Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Int'" ---> When using -= or +=). If you guys are wondering, this is a Snake arcade game, and the function above is what happens when the snake moves (left, right, up, down)

Any help of why this issue is happening or possibly how use a different yet similar version of increments and decrements (-- and ++)?

Comment: please update your question with a more useful title, something specific to the issue youre having.

Comment: which lines are you getting that error on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `--theX` is using the *pre-decrement operator*.  It decrements the value of the `theX` before using it, so:

This:

```
if --theX > 0 {
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
theX -= 1
if theX > 0 {
}
```

The same is true for the others.  If you were using a pre-decrement (`--value`) or a pre-increment (`++value`), then replace that with `value -= 1` or `value += 1` before using `value` on the next line.

---

The problem with your translation of `if --theX > 0` into `if theX - 1 > 0` is that the value of `theX` isn't being modified, so you'll use the wrong value for `theX` when you construct the `Point` in the `return Point(x: theX, y: theY)` statement.